# trying to make a bitmap editor in qt

Tags: qt, bitmap

I want to make a program using qt.
I have to make a bitmap editor for special purposes.
I had been looking widgets that could allow me to get this task done, one of them is QGraphicsView with QGraphicsScene.
As expected, I want my program to have many features.

They are listed below:

- Exporting to image formats such as .bmp.
- Support for clipboard, copy and paste. I hope this clipboard can be compatible with other similar programs.
- The image must have a resolution. I mean the pixels of the screen can be bigger than the pixels of the image and vice-versa.
- Selecting squared areas.

So, what I need to know is if I am using the correct widget. If not,  which widget can I use? which are the member functions of the widget that I need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There several ways to achieve what you want, but as your question is too broad, I would suggest looking at the Qt [Scribble](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html) example and come back with specific questions relating to what it *doesn't* do.

The link suggested previously was replaced with a new one that points to the corresponding Qt 5 example.